# Software Center doesn't load any app

Tags: 16.04, software-center

The new software center worked for some time for me but now wouldn't fetch anything from it's database. I get the circular loading sign and nothing loaded at all on the last two tabs, namely: 'Installed' and 'Updates'. Same problem with searching on the 'All' tab.
This is what it looks like

[image]

The last thing I remember doing is asking the software center to update five of the six applications available to be updated and leaving my computer at it.

Comment: general thing to do: start it from command line and watch for errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I started `software-center` from the terminal, Software Center gave an error message saying the package system was broken. I clicked repair and now everything is back to normal.